# Change the subsubsection numbering style

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How I can do this with `\subsubsection` just in this section because I would do just in this section and not in other section of report. It is possible to do this?

This is that I want to do:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Les étapes }
\subsubsection{1) un}
    texte........
\subsubsection{2) deux}
    texte........
\subsubsection{3) trois}
    texte........
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which numbers are subsubsection numbers in this image? You don't even give the code.

Comment: @Bernard I posted the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, with`titlesec` and `fmtcount`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\arabic{subsubsection})}{0.5em}{\numberstring{subsubsection}\enspace}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section{Les étapes }
\subsubsection{}
    texte........
\subsubsection{}
    texte........
\subsubsection{}
    texte........

\end{document}
```

*Unrelated*: If you have a recent version of LaTeX, you don't have to load `inputenc`, as `[utf8]` is nnow the default. Also, it is better to load the language options with the document class, to be sure all language-dependent packages be aware of the current language.
[image]

Comment: thank you that work just to understand why to use \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries

Comment: and to change the title of subsubsection ?

Comment: It is the default value in the report class. You might be in an environment where the font wouldbe, say `\Large` or `\mdseries`. It is a way to ensure we have the default values. Of course, if you want other values, you just have to change them.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘changing the title’?

Comment: instead of "un" or "deux" putting "a title of a stage"

Comment: thank you for your explication !

Comment: In this case, I would remove `\nimberstrin{\subsubsection}\endspace` and type `subsubsection{Titre du stage}`, (do I understand well what you'd like to have?)

Comment: yes but keeping the style only parenthesis if possible like this 1) title1

Comment: Just leave the last argument of `\titleformat` empty.

Comment: thank ypu that work

Comment: how to leave this change just in this place for example if i have another one and i want it to stay like this : 1.etape 1) lalaa 2.me   lalala (this is a a auther subsubsection  which is not numbered)

Comment: You can use `\titleformat{subsubsection}{…}` in the document body, enclosing it, with the subsubsections formatted in this style, between a pair of braces to make it local or between a pair `\bgroup ... \egroup`).

Comment: thank's it's work but when I leave \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
  it also changes the other parts

Comment: i put `\newenvironment{teste}
{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}%
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}}
{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}` and in before `\bgroup` i add  `\begin{teste}` it's correcte ?

Comment: I don't know, as I dont see exactly what you try to obtain. I set `secnumdepth` to 4 just in case you want to number \paragraphs, but if you don't number them, setting it to 3 is fine..

Comment: thank you for your help